# View.setWidth()?

Tags: android, java

Представляете, нет такого. Есть setMinWidth(), но это не то. Как быть?

Comment: Что за элемент то вообще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
params.width = width;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

с LayoutParams нужно пооисторожнее, есть несколько типов. Все зависит обычно от родительского контейнера этого view.